# Python, regex to split alphanumeric string with multiple separators

Tags: python, regex

Good morning,
I have a series of file names in the form `52798687KF_12712320CP.txt`, from which I extract four substrings, namely `52798687`, `KF`, `12712320`, and `CP`.

At present, I get those element through a sequence of rough split operations:

```
s = '52798687KF_12712320CP.txt'

f1 = s.split('_')[0][:-2])
f2 = s.split('_')[0][-2:])
f3 = s.split('_')[1][:-6])
f4 = s.split('_')[1][-6:-4])
```

I would like to achieve the same result with a single statement, resorting to a regular expression, since, as explained below, the name structure may vary with certain criteria.
However I got stuck, since I'm not able to compose the suitable sintax; after different attempts I came up with this partial solution:

```
import re

s = '52798687KF_12712320CP.txt'
reg = r"(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(_)|(.[a-z]{3})|(?=\d).(?<=\D)"
x = re.split(reg, s)
```

But it results in a list with too many elements:

```
['52798687', None, None, 'KF', '_', None, '12712320', None, None, 'CP', None, '.txt', '']
```

Whereas I want a list containing:

```
['52798687', 'KF', '12712320', 'CP']
```

Some details about each element:

1. at least one digit;
2. two letters, between the last digit and the underscore;
3. at least one alphanumeric character;
4. two letters ahead of the extension period.

Thank you ever so much!

Comment: What would be the result for `'1AA_A1AAA.txt'?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)(?:\.\w+$)?', s)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regular expression solution:

```
import re

s = '52798687KF_12712320CP.txt'
print(re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+", s.split(".")[0]))
```

**Output:**

```
['52798687', 'KF', '12712320', 'CP']
```

Answer (score 0):

As your third group can consist of a mix of alphanumerical characters, I'd do the following based on your 4-points list:

```
import re
reg = re.compile(r"(?i)^(\d+)([a-z]{2})_([a-z\d]+)([a-z]{2})\.")

s = "1AA_A1AAA.txt"  # sample input
m = reg.match(s)
if m:
    print(m.groups())  # ('1', 'AA', 'A1A', 'AA')
```